# A trigger on contentVersion object with additional logic

Tags: trigger, contentversion

I have a trigger on contentVersion. I also have a custom Object named (Term_and_condition__c). Whenever I attach some file to my custom object's (Term_and_condition__c) record, my trigger gets called. Now inside that trigger I would like to check if the file is attached to the Terms_and_condition__c object's record or any other object's (let say Account object) record.

Been stuck here for hours any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please share the code where you are stuck by [editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/363647/edit) your question to add what you have attempted so far and *exactly* (e.g., exact error text, details of unexpected behavior) how it is not working. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include.. .(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.")*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object  you are looking for is contentdocumentlink.

please go through salesforce documentation and understand relationship between contentversion , contentdocument and contentdocumentlink.

contentdocumentlink  stores  sharing details of document.
if you attach a file  to your object   Term_and_condition__c  then  contentdocumentlink records  will created  and  one such record  will have a linkedentityid  of your  Term_and_condition__c    record.

you can check linkedentityid  of the record and confirm on which objct doc is attached.

if you want to do it from contentversion trigger.

```
-> iterate over content version record using trigger.new  in after insert
-> store all contentdocumentids
-> query contentdocumentlink  associated with this contentdocumentids.
-> check linkedentityid  aand linkedntity.type  to find object associated  with file.
```

here is a sample code.please note it is not optimized and do not follow best practices.  it is just for sample logic.

```
trigger contentversiontrigger on ContentVersion (before insert,after insert,before update , after update) {

if(trigger.isinsert  && trigger.isafter) {

List<id> contentdocumentids = new List<id>();

for(contentversion cv : trigger.new) {

        contentdocumentids.add(cv.contentdocumentid);

}



list<contentdocumentlink>  CDLList = [select id,LinkedEntityId,linkedentity.type ,contentdocumentid   from contentdocumentlink where contentdocumentid  in :contentdocumentids];


system.debug('contentdocumentids' + CDLList);

}

}
```

salesforce link for contentdocumentlink  :  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Comment: linkedentity.type was the column that solved the problem.